# Push notifications with SignalR

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I am developing an application in .net core with SignalR. Users will be subscribed to the system. What I need to know is: Does a user have to be logged in to receive a notification? I would like for the notification to be pushed without them having to log in every time. It must be similar to a WhatsApp message that just "arrives". Is this possible with SignalR?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each active browser tab is one connection to SignalR (the *Client*), with a unique `ConnectionId`. Depending on the usage of notifications, a visitor does not have to be logged in. A connection with a SignalR Hub is established when the JavaScript code has been initialized.

You can simply invoke (call) a JavaScript function from the server for each *Client* (visitor). So all visitors will receive the notification:

```cs
await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotification", "Your notification message");
```

All connected clients will receive this 'event' from the server. Write a 'listener' for the `ReceiveNotification` event inside your JavaScript to do something client side:

```js
connection.on("ReceiveNotification", function (user, message) {
    // Show the notification.
});
```

---

#### Example

Depending on how you want to send a notification, you can either invoke the `ReceiveNotification`:

1. From the JavaScript;

```js
connection.invoke("SendMessage", user, message).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

2. From the Server (e.g. a controller), using [`IHttpContext<THub>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<SomeHub> _hubContext;

    public HomeController(IHubContext<SomeHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveNotifiction", "Your notification message");
        return View();
    }
}
```

Example (modified) is taken from the [SignalR HubContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.1) documentation.

Comment: @LukeVincent You're welcome. Please click on the green "Accept answer" icon to let other people know that this answer was helpful for you.