# How to update material design lite badge count

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

How can I update the data-badge count on a Material Design Lite badge in javascript? For example, the count of new notifications on a notification badge after fetching the notifications from the database.

Comment: I suggest you to search Asp.Net Signalr so that the numbers in the notification section can work synchronously with the database. similar example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901043/push-notifications-with-signalr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in Javascript:

```
let element = document.getElementById("#yourBadgeId");

element.setAttribute("data-badge" , yourValue);
```

make sure that in the html script, the mdl badge tag should not contain the data-badge attribute